# Yii Controller As Variable In URL

Tags: php, yii

Using the PHP framework Yii I want to have a url like url.com/xyz where xyz is an argument I want to pass to a specific controller (I wont know the value of this argument as it is dynamically generated). Is this possible? To my understanding Yii will see xyz as a controller and I am not sure how to change this without destroying the functionality of the rest of the site (url.com/controller/arg/etc)

Help? :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can do this. For example the if you set a [url rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#rules-detail)

```
'<view:\w+>'=>'site/page',
```

will treat anything of url.com/xyz to the `view` parameter of the action `page` of the controller `site`.

**THE PROBLEM IS THAT** the for every other routes you have to specify an action , or in other words [defaultAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#defaultAction-detail) of any other controller has no effect.

ie the url url.com/site WITHOUT the above rule will redirect to the `site/index` and to `site/page` with `view="index"` WITH the above rule

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the "URL management" chapter of the guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

A rule like the following would route a request to example.com/foo to the action `myaction` in `mycontroller`, giving the value foo to the parameter `name`.

```
 '<name>' => 'mycontroller/myaction'
```

This rule should be the last one in the rule list. Otherwise all requests would be passed to `myaction`, breaking existing parts of the site.